# GnuPlot not plotting over the whole range

Tags: gnuplot

Basicaly, I have the following code:

```
binom(n,k) = n!/(k!*(n-k)!)
hyperge(N,K,n,k) = binom(K,k)*binom(N-K,n-k)/binom(N,n)
hypergge(N,K,n,k) = sum [i=k:K] hyperge(N,K,n,i)    

set term png
set output "onedrop.png"
set xlabel "Decksize"
set ylabel "Chance of having one of four one-drops on turn 1"
plot [x=59:209] (hypergge(floor(x)-9,4,6,1) + (1-hypergge(floor(x)-9,4,6,1))*(hypergge(floor(x)-9,4,6,1)))*100 with lines notitle lw 2
```

(The only thing that might be really important about hypergge is that it use factorials, i.e. needs integers as arguments).

which produces the following output
[image]
So for some reason, gnuplot just stops drawing the plot at ~180, and I see absolutely no reason why it behaves like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`170!` is the last factorial which gnuplot can evaluate:

```
gnuplot> print 170!
7.257415615308e+306
gnuplot> print 171!
inf.0
```